# How to increase interval over time?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I was wondering on how do I increase the interval over time so I can add target. I am still new to cocos2d.

```
[self schedule:@selector(gameLogic:) interval:0.7];



 -(void)gameLogic:(ccTime)dt {
[self addTarget];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float interval = .7;

-(id)init{
  ...
  [self scheduleOnce:@selector(gameLogic:) delay:interval]; //Check the name of the method, I'm not 100% sure about it
  ...
}

-(void)gameLogic:(ccTime)dt {
  [self addTarget];
  interval += dt; //Or whatever you want to increase it by
  [self scheduleOnce:@selector(gameLogic:) delay:interval]; //Check the name of the method, I'm not 100% sure about it
}
```

Comment: It's `- (void) scheduleOnce:(SEL) selector delay:(ccTime) delay;` But otherwise, your answer should work fine!

Answer (score 2):

Why not declare a simple property (int, float, etc.) to hold the number of times your method has been called, and increment it when you call the method itself?  That way, it's just a multiplication problem:

```
//.h
...
@property (nonatomic, assign) int iterations;
//.m
@synthesize iterations = iterations_;
[self schedule:@selector(gameLogic:) interval:0.7*iterations_];

 -(void)gameLogic:(ccTime)dt {
    [self addTarget];
    iterations_++;
}
```

Comment: My apologies, I should read the header documentation first!  `If the selector is already scheduled, then the interval parameter will be updated without scheduling it again.`  So, your answer would work too. Sorry!